# c# Как сделать мультиязычное приложение?

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно сделать переключения языков на форме.

Чтобы при нажатие на Eng label ( кнопку ) показывался Английский текст в форме.

При нажатие на Rus label (кнопку ) показывался Русский текст в форме.

Пример:

Нажали на label (Eng) переключились на Английский текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажали на label (Rus) переключились на Русский текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте `Dictionary` англ-рус и рус-англ, из них можно будет брать сопоставленные слова для интерфейса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае это делается через ресурсы.
Здесь есть подробный пример
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/580043/How-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-Csharp